# Clicking on a non-interactive Selenium element

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing an electronic diary parser and ran into a problem. Sometimes they attach a file with homework. Here's the gist: I would like to download this file through Selenium, but to do this, you need to first click on an object that is not interactive, and then a download link will appear. But how to click on it if the object is not interactive?[This is the most non-interactive element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOngY.png)

I tried various options that the neural network advised me, but either I did something wrong, or the neural network was wrong. I would still like to know how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Xpath helped in searching for an element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).